# flChart line chart line overflow in x-axis

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello, I am new at asking question if you need more information about question you can leave a comment.
fl-chart is overflowing from bottom. How can I solve this problem?

I already try

```
clipData: FlClipData.all(),
```

Yaa it removes this overflow but it also remove some part of line but I only want to remove the overflow not overflow line. I want the line on bottom straight and I also want that it can't overflow
from bottom. So, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Need to set **curveSmoothness** value to **0.05** in **LineChartbarData** for not to overflow chart line in x-axis in FLchart.

Or set curveSmoothness value accordingly your usecase.

```
LineChartBarData(
            spots: model.chartBarData.map((e) => FlSpot(e.xValue, e.value)).toList(),
            isCurved: true,
            dotData: FlDotData(show: false),
            curveSmoothness: 0.05, // here need to set value
          )q
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `preventCurveOverShooting` to `true`.

```
    isCurved: true,
color: const Color(0xffCE9DD9),
show: active,
dotData: const FlDotData(
  show: false,
),
preventCurveOverShooting: true,
```